# How to convert byte data into integers and floats using python?

Tags: python, binary, data-files

I have a .bin binary file into which some data is written in the following representation.

- id1: (int,16 bit)
- id2: (int,16 bit)
- time: (int,64 bit)
- val1: (int, 16 bit)
- val2: (double, 64 bit)

I want to read and decode the data into human-readable format. So far I am only able to read the .bin file byte by byte but have no idea how to get the corresponding data values as integers and floats. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

This is how I am reading the file:

```
output = []

with open(filename,'rb') as fo:
    byte = fo.read(1)
    while byte:
        byte = fo.read(1)
        output.append(byte)
```

Comment: What do you read with ?

Comment: for integers you can use [from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) method

Comment: You probably want the `struct` modules. You can parse longer blocks of data with single calls to `struct.unpack`; no need to read data one byte at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try the methods from the struct module and see if I am able to achieve what I want.

Comment: What should be the 'format' for struct.unpack_from()? It should be 'hhqhd' according to the data representation and the total size of the buffer should be 22 bytes. But struct.calcsize('hhqhd') gives 32?

Comment: I have figured it out, I also needed to specify '<' Byte order, now the problem is solved. Thank you very much for your help.